# How can I access zend session in some other application that is integrated with it

Tags: zend-framework, session, zend-session, php, zend-session-namespace

I am running a Zend Framework application and I have to integrate a third party chat application and for that I need to have access of signed in user's ID, How can I access this id that is stored in Zend session.

Because this is not working

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['Zend_Auth']['storage']->user_id)) {
$userid = $_SESSION['Zend_Auth']['storage']->user_id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to get user id from storage

```
$userInfo = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->read();
echo $userInfo->user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks but Other application creates its own session and we can't access zend there. it will not work, either I have to include zend session or use cookies to remember user_id.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel more comfortable using your approach ($_SESSION) you can do it like this:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['Zend_Auth']['storage']['user_id'])) { // <- Changed from '->' to ['']
    $userid = $_SESSION['Zend_Auth']['storage']['user_id']; // <- same as above
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks but it will not work, either I have to include zend session or use cookies to remember user_id.